# How do ArrayList, static, and this work in Java?

Tags: java, static, arraylist, this, comparable

I was going through the article [Java Sorting: Comparator vs Comparable Tutorial](http://lkamal.blogspot.com/2008/07/java-sorting-comparator-vs-comparable.html), and have some questions about it.

```
List<Employee> col = new ArrayList<Employee>();

col.add(new Employee(5, "Frank", 28));
col.add(new Employee(1, "Jorge", 19));
col.add(new Employee(6, "Bill", 34));
col.add(new Employee(3, "Michel", 10));
col.add(new Employee(7, "Simpson", 8));
col.add(new Employee(4, "Clerk", 16));
col.add(new Employee(8, "Lee", 40));
col.add(new Employee(2, "Mark", 30));

return col;
```

1. This is an ArrayList of Employee objects. How many items can I add in this employee object? Can I do something like this?

   ```
   col.add(new Employee(5, "Frank", 28, "asas", "asas"));
   ```

   This is basically an array of Objects like `Array[0]` contains all these. And I am actually trying to access these array of Objects via `ArrayList`.
2. Why is the `printList` made static? Can I also have other types here?

   ```
    private static void printList(List<Employee> list) {
        System.out.println("EmpId\tName\tAge");
        for (Employee e: list) {
            System.out.println(e.getEmpId() + "\t" + e.getName() + "\t" + e.getAge());
        }
    }
   ```
3. While comparing, what does `this` represent and `o` represent?

   ```
   public int compareTo(Employee o) {
        return this.empId - o.empId;
   }
   ```

   What does `this` mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how many items can i add?

You can add items to the list until the Java VM runs out of memory. There is no artificial limit.

> can i do something like this?

```
col.add(new Employee(5, "Frank", 28, "asas", "asas"))
```

No, because the `Employee` has no constructor which takes these arguments. But you can

```
col.add(new Employee(5, "Frank", 28));
```

This gives you two very similar but not identical instances in the list (they aren't identical because they are at different places in memory; they are similar because all fields have the same value).

> Why does the printList made static?

So it can be called from the static method `main()` without creating an instance of `TestEmployeeSort`

> what does this represent and o represent?

The sort algorithm will select two items in the list and call `compareTo()` on one with the other as argument. The former will be `this`, the latter will be in `o`.

This way, the sort algorithm doesn't need to know much about the objects it compares.

The advantage is that you can easily make objects comparable. The drawback is that the list must not contain `null` pointers or non-`Employee` instances.

If that doesn't work for you, you can create a `Comparator` which also has a `compareTo` method but it takes *two* arguments.

Comment: How do we get the Employee e: list in the printList method... do i need to import the Employee class...

Answer (score 2):

John,

1. col.add accepts only one Bject. So, you creates one Employee object with a new operation and adds it a list. So, you cannot use this - new Employee(5, "Frank", 28, "asas", "asas"), because Employee object doesn't have such constructor. Evene if it has such constructor it creates only one Employee object.
2. printLine is static, because you need to create TestEmployeeSortobject first, to use non-static  method. But it doesn't have any sense (to create non-static object) because printLine doesn't use internal state of TestEmployeeSortobject, so, it can be and must be static in this case.
3. compareTo defines whi is bigger than other one. See the API:
   Returns:
   a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

So, in that case author decides that Employee is greater if Id is greater. You can change that method to use any other field to define sorting order.

Answer (score 1):

**this** references the current instance of your object , **o** is the Employee parameter of the compareTo function. You can't sort a list without knowing how to compare the Objects in the List, in this case you compare the employee ids.

Also it would be more elegant to do a
`System.out.println(e.toString());`

and overriding toString method for Employee, instead of calling getters for each field.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can add more "items" to the Employee object if you modify it's class variables and constructor:

   public class Employee {
       private int empId;
       private String name;
       private int age;

   ```
   // add new var
   private Object x;

   public Employee(int empId, String name, int age) {
       // set values on attributes
   }

   // add new construct
   public Employee(int empId, String name, int age, Object x) {
       //set the other attributes

       // this.x represents the current instance's x property, and x represents the parameter from the construct
       this.x = x;
   }
   // getters & setters
   ```

   }

To get objects I would recomment myList.get(index)...

1. You can add the new variable in the printList method, of course.
2. see the answer from @Sleeperson

Answer (score 1):

First question: No you can't unless there is another constructor that is

```
Employee (int, String, int, String, String)
```

Second question: I'm unsure what you are asking...I'm sure someone else can help though.

Third question: "this" represents the Employee calling the method compareTo and "o" represents the employee that is passed as an argument. Most compareTo methods return 0 if the objects are equal and in this case, anything else if the objects aren't.  So this method compares employee ids.  If it is the same Employee, this.empId - o.empId will return 0

Answer (score 1):

> Can i do something like this?

Yes.

```
col.add(new Employee(5, "Frank", 28, "asas", "asas"))
```

is same as

```
Employee e = new Employee(5, "Frank", 28, "asas", "asas");
col.add(e);
```

> How many items can i add in this employee object

You meant the list right? There is no practical limit.

> Why does the `printList` made static?

This `printList` method is a *utility* method. This does not have nothing to do with the data of the class, and does some, well, utilities, and does not have to be present in every instance of the method. Methods doing some formatting, logging and such stuff are generally static.

> While comparing... what does this represent and o represent.

In `compareTo`, this is the current object on which `compareTo` is called, and `o` is the object passed on to it.
So when you say `e1.compareTo(e2)`, `e1` is this and `e2` is `o`.